# PHP - Pass by reference a variable number of arguments

Tags: php, reference

I know you can pass a variable number of arguments to a function an access them individually.

For example

```
function foo()
{
    $arg = func_get_arg(0);
    $arg += 10;
}

$a = 100;

foo($a);

echo "A is $a\n";
```

But those arguments are passed by value as demonstrated above.

Is it possible to use them as if they was passed by reference in a similar manner to functions like `bind_param` in the mysqli library?

Comment: perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php, example #3, can help you

Comment: @Amir Example 3 does not help with variable number of arguments because you usually omit these arguments from the method signature, so you cannot signify them with &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I want to mention: [Don't use references](http://www.schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html).

That aside: Doing that directly is impossible as the engine has to know whether something is a reference before calling the function. What you can do is passing an array of references:

```
$a = 1; $b = 2; $c = 3;
$parameters = array(&$a, &$b, &$c, /*...*/);
func($parameters);

function func(array $params) {
    $params[0]++;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with references if you know what you are doing (and I would to implement a function that can modify multiple arguments upon completion). Any enough of the plug for your web site.

Comment: Well in 99% of the cases there are better designs than using references. For instance using object-oriented designs. An object-oriented design can be cleaner, more maintainable and, especially with PHP 5.4, be faster and require less memory.

Comment: Where does the 99% come from?

Comment: Obviously not a scientific number, but a conclusin after almost 15 years of using PHP and about 10 years of working on the engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cant, simply you cant tell the php that this is by reference and that is not, But! I recommend doing the following :

```
function foo()
{
    $arg = func_get_arg(0);
    $arg->val += 10;
}
$a =new stdClass();
$a->val = 100;
foo($a);
echo "$a\n"; // 110
```

you can apply boxing to the value you want and it works, 
Hope you find this helpful, if you have any questions please ask.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Do not make edits that add substantial amounts of extra information. Do so in a comment or in a new answer.